# How to get all element parents using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to get all element parents using jquery? i want to save these parents in a variable so i can use later as a selector.
such as `<div><a><img id="myImg"/></a></div>` 
GetParents('myImg'); will return "div a" something like that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

/// Get an array of all the elements parents:

```
allParents = $("#myElement").parents("*")
```

/// Get the nested selector through an element's parents:

```
function GetParents(id) {
    var parents = $("#" + id).parents("*");
    var selector = "";
    for (var i = parents.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selector += parents[i].tagName + " ";
    }

    selector += "#" + id;

    return selector;
}
```

GetParents('myImage') will return your nested selector: HTML BODY DIV A #myImage

### Note sure why you'd want this but its reuseable as a selector.

Comment: `'#' + id` is not safe. If "id" contains `[]` or other special characters (which are legal), this won't work. Better to use `document.getElementById` here, or at least escape it properly.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to grab their selectors, as you can use them directly with jQuery afterwards.

If you want to use all parents later, you can do something like:

```
var parents = $("#element").parents();
for(var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++){
  $(parents[i]).dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Every element has only one real parent. To access and save it, write the following:

```
myParent = $("#myElement").parent();
```

If you need the parents parents too, use .parents()

See documentation for further information:

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent#expr

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr

Comment: But that parent has a parent and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parents() to get your immediate parent, and their parents on up the tree.  you can also pass a selector as an arg to only get parents that match a certain criteria.  For instance:

```
$('#myelement').parents('[id$=container]')
```

to get all parents who have an id attribute whose value ends with the text "container"

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the tags of an element's parents like this:

```
var sParents = $('#myImg').parents('*').map(function() {                
      return this.tagName;
    }).get().join(' ');
```

you can also replace *this.tagName* with *this.id* for example or other attributes

Comment: liked this solution, will test it, but seams smart.