# How to calculate the relationship between two DOM elements? I.e. how close(ly related) they are

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to find a way to tell the distance between two DOM elements. Not in pixels, but as in traversal steps.

The practical use of this would be the following: There is one core element, that needs to find other similar elements in the site, and mimic the behavior of the closest related.

E.g. a gallery without a set width, in tabs. The invisible tabs could have no width, thus the gallery in the tab will not be visible unless it's reinitialized when the tab is shown. The hidden gallery would be the core element and it will to look for another possible instances of the gallery which is working properly and copy its width in order to work. The working gallery could be in the first tab, or in the content, or a small gallery in the sidebar or footer. What I'd like is for it to 'know' that the closest related other instance is the one on the other tab, not the one in the footer. Since this is a WP plugin I can't hardcode anything, and the scenario is not just limited to tabs.

`.closest()` doesn't work for this purpose.

Comment: why you posted  question and answer your self with in 1 min ??

Comment: During writing it I realized I can find a solution without posting the question. Then I didn't want to cancel the question, I decided to post the answer so others can benefit from the finding.

Comment: @Baadshah Because the OP has shared his knowledge with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that for this pupose the most efficient solution is this:

`var commonParentsDepth = a.parents().has(b).first().parents().length;`

You'll get a number that tells you how deep the two elements' common ancestor is. You do this test in a loop for multiple elements, comparing two at a time, one of which does not change. You'll be able to tell by the result if two elements are closer related than others. The larger the number, the deeper down the tree your two elements are, which means the closer they are.

Note: This is not for comparing two elements against another two.

I've combined these two, somewhat related questions:

- [How to find the nearest common ancestors of two or more nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960843/how-to-find-the-nearest-common-ancestors-of-two-or-more-nodes)
- [JS/jQuery: Get depth of element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710943/js-jquery-get-depth-of-element)