# Finding out which element exactly was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to test which parts of a page are clicked. Is there a jQuery function that can show the path of the element that is being clicked? I have searched Google but have not come across anything that has worked for me. Is `event.target.className` correct to use for this?

Code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").click(function(event) {
            window.alert("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: And how does your code look like? have you have an argument called event?

Comment: Are you after a specific attribute of the clicked element? Or just which element? If so... `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM element that was clicked is simply [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Comment: Is there a way to get the full path of that DOM element?

Comment: you can use $(event.target).parents() to get all the element's ancestors. What is your objective?

Comment: I have updated my posting with some code. This works for me, but on shows me `span` for example. Is there a way to get the full path that leads to that particular `span`?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you call the "full path"? Does it just include node names, or are you also looking for class names and ids? btw the title of your question is a little bit misleading...

Comment: Node names, class names, and ids.

Comment: [Refer This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748842/how-to-get-all-element-parents-using-jquery)   @three3

Answer (score 3):

This may be help you :

```
<script> 
  document.onclick = function(evt) {
    var evt=window.event || evt; // window.event for IE
    if (!evt.target) evt.target=evt.srcElement; // extend target property for IE
    alert(evt.target); // target is clicked
  }
</script>
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery) also be helpfull

Comment: as the OP is using jQuery, evt.target is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the element, its just `event.target`, selected as `$(event.target)` in jQuery,

If looking for clicked element's class,

Yes `event.target.className` is valid,

If you want other functions in jQuery,

You may try,

```
$(event.target).attr('class');
```

OR

```
$(event.target).prop("class");
```

**Edit after comments**

To get all the parents listed,

get all the parents, and add their node name to a variable,

```
var a = "";
a += event.target.nodeName;
$(event.target).parents().each(function(){
     a += " < "+$(this)[0].nodeName;
});
alert(a);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/22/)**

Comment: Is there a way to get the full path of that DOM element?

Comment: If you mean selecting the element in jquery, `$(event.target)` selects the element. If not, I didn't get what you mean by full path.

Comment: I have updated my posting with some code. This works for me, but on shows me `span` for example. Is there a way to get the full path that leads to that particular `span`?

Comment: Full path, you mean listing all the parents starting from body?

Comment: @OptimusPrime your > should actually be <

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    console.log($(event.target).attr('class'));
});
```

would work fine. It would probably be better to use id's though. In that case, the syntax is a little more efficient

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: I have updated my posting with some code. This works for me, but on shows me `span` for example. Is there a way to get the full path that leads to that particular `span`?